# Display toolbar options on breadcrumbs

Tags: magento-1.9, toolbar, breadcrumbs

Is there a way to get Product List Toolbar into `breadcrumbs.phtml`? All I want to do is display toolbar options inside the breadcrumbs wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1240/54615

If you want to apply this on product listing page change `catalog_category_layered` to `catalog_category_view`

Answer (score 0):

in `local.xml`

```
<your_layout_handle>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/1column.phtml` if you are using a 1column template, then add this below a `breadcrumbs` child:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_list_toolbar') ?>
```

Nb: you can add a new crumb `<action method="addCrumb">` but not directly a block.

Comment: I did that. But it gives me a Fatal Error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on null`

Comment: look my update.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still getting the same error. I did try with `catalog_category_view` handle and `default` handle.